# WCF Issue : The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to upload a file to WCF service from the application itself.My WCF service is like this:

```
<WebInvoke(UriTemplate:="uploadimage?name={name}", Method:="Post")>
    Function UploadImage(ByVal stream As Stream, ByVal name As String) As String
```

I am trying to invoke it in the same project on the button click like this:

```
 Protected Sub btntest_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btntest.Click

I am using IIS hosting within same project.

        Dim req As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost:29723/HighriseeSite/appservices.svc" & "/uploadimage?name="), HttpWebRequest)
        req.Method = "POST"
        req.ContentType = "text/plain"
        Dim reqStream As Stream = req.GetRequestStream()
        Dim fileToSend As Byte() = New Byte(12344) {}
        For i As Integer = 0 To fileToSend.Length - 1
              fileToSend(i) = CByte("a"c & (i Mod 26))
        Next
        reqStream.Write(fileToSend, 0, fileToSend.Length)
        reqStream.Close()
        Dim resp As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Console.WriteLine("HTTP/{0} {1} {2}", resp.ProtocolVersion, CInt(resp.StatusCode), resp.StatusDescription)
```

Comment: Hi. webHttpBinding supports parameters in front of the Stream body parameter, other bindings do not and there must either be a single Stream parameter or a message contract with headers and a stream body